# Killall processes under a user?

Tags: linux, process, users, kill

So, I know you can `pkill -U <uid>`, but whenever I've used this, my entire system crashes. Further investigation shows it probably is because I'm not matching anything, so it matches everything? How can I effectively kill all processes running under a user?

Comment: When you crash the system, what UID are you trying to kill?  If you try to kill everything run by root, well, you're going to be in for a bad time. . .

Comment: @EricRenouf No, It's a UID in the 6800s. I did this, though: `killall -u ap_6857 -l -i`, and got, `HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT IOT BUS FPE KILL USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM
STKFLT CHLD CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU URG XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH IO PWR SYS
UNUSED
`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your command was showing.  Did you do `killall -u ap_6857 -l -i` and see all the other things as output?  If so, that's what the `-l` flag is for, to list the available signals to send?

Comment: `pkill -U nonexistant-userid` should kill nothing, not everything... Are you doing something like killing the userid you're logged in under? What does `pgrep -U <uid>` show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use killall to kill, or send any other signal, to a bunch of processes at once. One of the "filtering" options is the owner:

```
 killall --user name1
```

I don't like killall (using it on solaris can cause disaster).

pkill is more portable

```
pkill -u username
```

Comment: I ended up settling on `ps -u 6857 -o pid --no-headers` and just kill <uid>, but this may work for others.

Comment: May be it's  respawn mode.